# Seeking experiments that are the basis of the 100-step limit

Tags: reaction-time, connectionism

I've read many times of the 100-step limit: since people respond to most complex stimuli in under 500 ms, and neurons take about 5 ms (or more) to switch state in response to a new stimulus, the calculation performed by the brain is limited to propagation through about 100 layers of neurons. I have only seldom found this illustrated with examples, though. The 100-step limit was first pointed out in "Connectionist Models and Their Properties" (Feldman & Ballard, 1982), which gives no examples and only cites the book *Chronometric Explorations of Mind* (Posner, 1978). This book is not readily available.

I've come across brief mentions that we can recognize a face or a word in 450 ms or so, but no real examples of experiments that measured this. Can you tell me some examples that clearly illustrate complex processing running to completion within this time frame?

(I'm interested in this partly to understand the difference between the "subsymbolic" processing that happens relatively fast and the slower processing of consciously reasoning something out, which takes much longer.)

Comment: 100 layers sounds like far too many to me, 5 ms is extremely optimistic. Brains are massively parallel, not serial processors. For the estimates you're looking for I'd recommend starting with psychophysics and reaction time rather than neural activity. Once you find those and want to move to neural stuff, I'd start with the perceptual decision making literature especially Shadlen and Newsome with random dot motion and the hundreds of offshoot papers in that area.